# How do I convert a JToken to nested list of floats?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to read in a JSON file using C# consisting of three fields: "name" and "ID", both strings, and "bitmask", which was written out from Python in the nested list format

```
[[0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0], ...].
```

Reading the file and accessing the string fields is no problem, but I haven't been able to crack the "bitmask" field. Ultimately I want to be able to put the fields into a dictionary to process into a database later.

I am new to C#, so my approaches have been a bit naive. I attempted to cast it as a `List<List<float>>` with no luck, as it appears you have to add each sublist iteratively. Is what I am trying to do even possible in C#? Here is my basic read-in code (taken from another extremely helpful post!).

I have access to the Python code that wrote out the JSONs, so if there is a different format for the lists that would make it possible to read in, I can re-process them.

```
using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(@"C:\Users...\data2.json"))
using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(file))
{
    JObject o2 = (JObject)JToken.ReadFrom(reader);
    string n = (string)o2.SelectToken("name");
    Console.WriteLine("Name field from JSON: {0}", n);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: What does each subelement in the "nested list format" mean as far as a bitmask? Note: In C#, a cast is restricted to only certain implicit conversions, otherwise it is just a reinterpretation of existing bits, and generally only useful with `object` or numeric data types.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there are no strings in that json, and if I understand your json correctly, each element only have 2 values, both floats. Can you please explain what you mean by name, id being strings? Where are they?

Comment: Or are you saying that that array of arrays of floats *is* your bitmask field? If so then no, you need to explain more about how this even is a bitmask. A bitmask is an integer, not a list, not a float.

Comment: The field is just called bitmask, a name of convenience. It is a 2D array that corresponds to an image which is processed separately. I haven't explicitly listed out the "name" and "id" fields, which are populated by short strings, because I am not having any trouble reading and processing those fields.

Comment: try `var bitmask = o2["bitmask"].ToObject<List<List<float>>>();`

Comment: @BrianRogers that worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casting a [`JToken`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm) to a `List<List<float>>` will not work because `JToken` only has explicit conversion operators for simple values like `string`, `int`, `bool`, `double`, etc.  (See [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_op_Explicit.htm) for the full list.)  To convert a complex object you should use the [`ToObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToObject.htm) method instead:

```
var bitmask = o2["bitmask"].ToObject<List<List<float>>>();
```